# Set site title & tagline with wp.config or function.php

Tags: php, functions, wp-config

Currently I can change `Site Title` & `Tagline` in Settings >> General but someone attack and remove it.

So now I want to set these via function.php or wp-config.php

Any Idea?

Comment: If you've been hacked, this isn't going to help you. If the attacker is able to edit these settings, they are very likely to be able to edit your theme files. You have much bigger issues that need to be solved than trying to make these uneditable.  Please review https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fields have the keys `'blogname'` and `'blogdescription'` respectively in the options table.

I'm not sure exactly why you need to do this as it seems like a priority to secure your site and be able to update it through the dashboard yourself, but you can update them easily from `functions.php` with `update_option`, e.g.:

```
update_option( 'blogname', "site title goes here" );

update_option( 'blogdescription', "site tagline does here" );
```